# How to use xdg-desktop-portal file portals in Java

Tags: java, linux, flatpak

GTK+ and Qt have xdg-desktop-portal functionality built-in, but it's unclear to me how to implement this functionality in Java.

How would one go about doing this? Are there any examples or packages to simplify implementation?

EDIT: To be specific, I need to be able to open an "open file" or "save as" dialogs, as described in the [xdg-desktop-portal README](https://github.com/flatpak/xdg-desktop-portal/blob/master/README.md).

Answer (score 0):

Normally, it would be the task of the JDK to provide the necessary integrations with the desktop environment, since it's on a "lower layer" than what you normally need to care about.

That being said, there's been a [similar issue](https://github.com/flatpak/xdg-desktop-portal/issues/519) that was raised in the flatpak repository for this exact same problem. In that issue and linked pull request, a workaround is specified: by executing `xdg-open $YOUR_URI`, you can get the same XDG-compliant behaviour.

Comment: Will try, thanks!
Will this work to open the "Open file" dialog too?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't seem to get an "Open file" dialog this way. Any ideas on how to do that?